# faild to send multi string to whatsapp

Tags: c#, whatsapp

i have 3 strings(c sharp)  and want to send them to whatsapp ,the whatsapp accept the 3 string as one string

**your text**

```
            string[] tempArray = richTextBox1.Lines;//3 strings in richTextBox1

                for (counter = 0; counter < tempArray.Length-1; counter++)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tempArray[counter]);
                    len = tempArray[counter].Length;

                    sw.WriteLine("tempArray" + tempArray[counter], len.ToString());

                    tempArray[counter].CopyTo(0, chary, 0, len);

                    CleanedString[counter] = "";
                        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
                         CleanedString[counter] += chary[j].ToString();

                //CleanedString[counter] = CleanedString[counter] + "\r\n";//did not work
                //CleanedString[counter] = CleanedString[counter] + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.Enter;//did not work
                CleanedString[counter] = CleanedString[counter] +  Keys.Enter;//did not work
                }
```

Comment: which error exactly do you get as text

Comment: multiline richTextBox has 3 strings i collected them to 1 string and send them to whatsapp they were receved as 1 string  like this string1string2string3 they should be allignened vertically .     \r\n has no  affect in whatsapp

Comment: in c3 code i have 3 seprate strings when sent to whatsapp whatsapp send all of them as one single string no separation in between i meam=n no \r\n

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
 %0a
```

So the text would be like

```
smsContain = txtName.Text +  "%0a %0a" + txtbox1.Text +  "%0a" + Textbox2.Text
```

Comment: Or, you could use the more traditional C# `"\n"`:  `smsContain = $"{txtName.Tex}\n\n{txtbox1.Text}\n{Textbox2.Text}";` (using an interpolated string)